# Why is auto click to open alert window or lightbox not working in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In my standalone html file, when I tried the code below, it works fine and on every page load, it brings up the alert window as expected.

However when I tried the same code and used it in `header.php` and `footer.php` in Wordpress, it does not fire up. Even when I click the link, it does not do anything. I am trying to do something similar with lightbox. Can someone advise why this is not working in WP?

```
<a class="test" href="#">Test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".test").click(function () {
        alert('My test');
      });
      $(".test").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure that jQuery is included?

Comment: @Krishna Yes jQuery is included in the `<head>`. I am using the default Twenty Thirteen template.

Comment: @Krishna Even when I click the link, it does not do anything. See if you can suggest something.

Comment: Do some debugging yourself. Open the developer console. Try typing `$('.test')` and see if any elements are selected. Try putting a break point in your `ready` function and seeing what the state of the DOM is there. We can't do any of this for you, you need to learn how to debug things for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find in alot of WP themes, jQuery is loaded in noConflict mode, in which case the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available. Try changing the JS to-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".test").click(function () {
        alert('My test');
        return false;
      });
      jQuery(".test").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I just realised that and fixed it. That did not come to my mind before I posted the question. Thanks anyway.